# Managing my bookmarks and the related file .emacs.bmk

Tags: bookmarks

Is there a way to change the location of the file `.emacs.bmk`? I tried doing it but then my bookmarks would not be found. I could not find how to customise the location of this file (similar issue with .emacs.d). Now I have a symlink but I would rather declutter my home folder.

Also, I just deleted a lot of my bookmarks from the list (using `C-x r l` (bookmark-bmenu-list) then d for the bookmarks to delete, x to execute) and the bookmarks were deleted (I can't find them using `C-x r b`) but they are all still in the file `.emacs.bmk` . Why is that the case? How can I delete bookmarks and have them removed from .emacs.bmk?

Comment: Please do a little background research before posting.  A web search for [emacs bookmark](https://www.google.com/search?q=emacs+bookmark&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) yields the [EmacsWiki page on bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookMarks) and the [manual page on bookmarks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bookmarks.html) as the first two hits, and both explain that you need to adjust `bookmark-default-file`.

Comment: @Dan, yes, and maybe if someone answered the question, then when the next person did a google search they would find this page, and perhaps start using Emacs.StackExchange, which is what we all want, isn't it?

Comment: I will add that also people already using this site might see the question and get ideas for things they can do with their emacs. I think you are being narrow minded by telling me to "google search". This message sends people away and it is not helpful.

Comment: Recommendable as EmacsWiki (and the manual) is for learning, StackExchange is way better in teaching.

Comment: I am not trying to drive you away from the site, I am trying to let you know that there is an [expectation of basic preliminary research](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/178/how-much-background-research-before-posting-a-question). A reasonable rule of thumb is that, if one can do a web search for "emacs + (noun from your question)" and the answer is contained in the first hit, then one needs to do a little more research. It is not unusual for people to downvote questions that display a lack of research effort; I used a comment to short-circuit the "uninformative downvote" route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Load the library: `M-x load-library RET bookmark RET`.
2. Customize your bookmarks file using `M-x customize-option RET bookmark-default-file`.  Completion is available for the option names, so type `bookm TAB` to see the options concerning bookmarks, etc.
3. After you delete bookmarks from your bookmark list, which is in memory, if you want those changes saved then you need to *save your bookmarks file*.  In the bookmark display list (from `C-x r l`), use `s` to save. As usual in Emacs, you can use `C-h m` in that buffer to see available keys/commands and other information about the mode.
4. For more information about bookmarks (as for other subjects), consult the Emacs manual: `C-h r`. Then use `i` to look topics up in the index (with completion). For example, `C-h r i bookmark RET`.
5. For extra bookmark features, see library [Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus).